# DataGrid RowDetails Visibility on RowDoubleClick

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, visibility, rowdetails

In my Datagrid xaml I set the rowdetailsvisibilitymode to collapsed.

Then I created an event on RowDoubleClick to collapse and expand the details of a row when the row is double clicked:

```
private void DgRowDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    var row = (DataGridRow)sender;
    row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed ?
        Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Now I want to collapse those details when a new row is selected... I want to imitate visiblewhenselected, but using a doubleclick.

My thoughts are: If possible; the details of a row collapse when a new row is selected, but the new row doesn't expand until doubleclicked. A second doubleclick should also be able to collapse the details of a currently selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the DataGrid RowSelected event. On this event Hide the previous row.
Now in order access the previous row the easy way out will be to hold the reference in your double click event. Something like this:

```
    DataGridRow visibleDetailRow = null;
    private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        visibleDetailRow = (DataGridRow)sender;
        visibleDetailRow.DetailsVisibility = visibleDetailRow.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed ?
            Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void DataGridRow_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(visibleDetailRow != null)
            visibleDetailRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

I am not sure if you are using MVVM in your code, perhaps it could have been handled in a more elegant way by binding your details visibility using MVVM, however, the solution just extends on your code.